# How can i open an hidden cmd in java and then write on it commands?

Tags: java, cmd, process, command, runtime

What i want to do is open a new cmd as the application starts and then write on it different commands in different moments.
Example: i start my application, it runs a new cmd that is hidden so it can't be seen, and then it writes "cd ..", the application wait ten seconds(for example) and then it writes "cd .." another time and finally it writes "dir" and it prints out the results of 'dir' command.
I've tryed to use this code to do that

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process process = rt.exec("cmd /c cd .. ");
    process = rt.exec("cmd /c cd .. ");

    process = rt.exec("cmd /c dir");
    BufferedReader commReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    String line = "";

    while((line = commReader.readLine()) != null){

        System.out.println(line);
    }

}
```

but as i've seen it doesn't work because it runs command on different cmds.
So sorry for my terrible english and does anyone know how to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting your `process` variable so of course it's going to execute multiple instances of cmd.

What you need to do is open a single process and then write commands to its `OutputStream` which is connected to the normal input of the sub-process.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd");
        Process process = builder.start();

        OutputStream stdin = process.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stdin));

        writer.write("cd ..\n");
        writer.write("dir\n");
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

        BufferedReader commReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";

        while((line = commReader.readLine()) != null){

            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
```